# Webpack MicroFrontends & sass configuration

Tags: webpack, sass, babeljs, micro-frontend

Trying to use SCSS inside my react MicroFrontendsApp.

But looks like there are some problems with webpack.

I'm using all the essential loaders for css/scss inside my webpack config, but the simple import of bootstrap inside index.js triggers an error.

index.js:

```
import('./bootstrap')
```

webpack.common.js:

```
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin')

module.exports = {
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.m?js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
          options: {
            presets: ['@babel/preset-react', '@babel/preset-env'],
            plugins: ['@babel/plugin-transform-runtime'],
          },
        },
      },
    ],
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: './public/index.html',
    }),
  ],
}
```

The error I get:

```
Uncaught Error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js):
SassError: expected "{".
  ╷
  │ import('./bootstrap')
  │                      ^
  ╵
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are using here is a [dynamic import](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/import), which returns a promise, so you should either write it with `await` or `then/catch`. I'm not sure why you use a relative import either but let's say that what you want:

```js
(async () => {
  if (somethingIsTrue) {
    await import("./bootstrap");
  }
})();
```

```
import("./bootstrap").then(...).catch(...);
```

And if you don't want to use a dynamic import, you can just write a [static import](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import):

```
import "./bootstrap";
```